# Calling a function after updating the state more than 1 time

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

I am storing some data in the state. I first call 1 API and get the update the data in the state 3 times. After the data update, I have to call another API using the updated state data. I am unable to do so . If the state was updated just once, I would have use useEffect. But, here it is changing 3 times.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(() => getDataInit());


const setDataKey = key => value =>
  setData(d => ({
    ...d,
    [key]: value,
}));

const postFn = () => {
  const response = await updateData({ body: data });
  onSave({
    response,
    widget,
    wrapperId,
  });
};

const resetFn = () => {
  const defaultData = await getDefaultData({
    query: { id: data.default_id },
  });
  setDataKey('quantity')(defaultData.quantity);
  setDataKey('name')(defaultData.name);
  setDataKey('amount')(defaultData.amount);
  postFn();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update to call only one `setData`. So you can add `useEffect` to call `postFn`

```
const resetFn = () => {
  const defaultData = await getDefaultData({
    query: { id: data.default_id },
  });

  const newData = {
   quantity: defaultData.quantity,
   name: defaultData.name,
   amount: defaultData.amount,
  };

  setData((d) => ({
    ...d,
    ...newData,
  }));
}

useEffect(() => {
  postFn();
}, [data]);
```